# How to set ul width in percent?

Tags: html, css

I have html:

```
<div class="wd">
    <ul id="postlist">
        <li><span class="num">h1</span>
            <ul>
                <li><span class="dt">h2</span>
                    <ul>
                         <li><span class="pun">h3</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span class="num">1<br/>11<br/>111</span>
            <ul>
                <li><span class="dt">1.1</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><span class="pun">1.1.1</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span class="num">2<br/>2</span>
            <ul>
                <li><span class="dt">2.1</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><span class="pun">2.1.1</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

how to set with css width of `#postlist` 100%, `.num`,`.dt`,`.pun` - 33% each?

http://jsfiddle.net/mma75kq7/

Comment: Are you trying to build a table? What is the layout suppose to look like?  Can you draw a picture?

Comment: @MarcAudet in jsfiddle table. I want width 100% and 33% columns

Comment: Width 100% only on #wd

Comment: Is the HTML that you presented absolutely critical?  There might be simpler ways of marking this up.  Please comment, thank you!

Comment: Not critical, but it need not <table> - ul li

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pull that off, but you'll need to change your css a bit:

- outer wrapper, `.wd` set it to display table & 100% width, or if you plan on having something else inside it, maybe wrap the whole  thingy in a div of its own with display table and 100% width
- the top `<li>` set it to have the width of 33.3333%
- then the `<ul>` inside the `<ul>` give it a width of 66.6666%
- the `<li>` inside the children `<ul>`, with `.dt` and another `ul`, set both children to display table cell, and the same for the next children
- and it should get going.

**Alternatively** you could just use a regular `<table>` if you plan on displaying tabular data, instead of pouring css rules to mimic the table behavior.(seems like a awful amount of markup to pull off 'undercover' table )

Check out the **[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ytk2v5hy/1/)** or the snippet bellow:

```css
.wd {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
ul {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  list-style: none outside none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
ul ul {
  width: 66.6666%;
}
li {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.num {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 33.3333%;
}
.dt {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
}
.pun {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
}
ul#postlist >li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wd">
  <ul id="postlist">
    <li><span class="num">h1</span>
      <ul>
        <li><span class="dt">h2</span>
          <ul>
            <li><span class="pun">h3</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span class="num">1<br/>11<br/>111</span>
      <ul>
        <li><span class="dt">1.1</span>
          <ul>
            <li><span class="pun">1.1.1</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span class="num">2<br/>2</span>
      <ul>
        <li><span class="dt">2.1</span>
          <ul>
            <li><span class="pun">2.1.1</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The mark-up was a bit convoluted and you got it to work, well worth an up vote!

Answer (score 1):

I, belatedly, offer the following simplified HTML and CSS that achieves the same result.

```css
.wd {
    width:100%;
}
ul#postlist {
    display: table;
    width:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul#postlist > li {
    display:table-row;
}
.num, .dt, .pun {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    list-style: none outside none;
    width: 33.333333333%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wd">
    <ul id="postlist">
        <li>
            <div class="num">h1</div>
            <div class="dt">h2</div>
            <div class="pun">h3</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="num">1
                <br/>11
                <br/>111</div>
            <div class="dt">1.1</div>
            <div class="pun">1.1.1</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="num">2.
                <br/>2..</div>
            <div class="dt">2.1</div>
            <div class="pun">2.1.1</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution seems a bit cleaner, something to take into consideration, although I'd take a regular table all day long :) +1

Comment: @Crispy-George I agree, in this case, regular table mark-up is exactly what is needed, this is indeed, tabular data! All the best!